# pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios-simulator, xcode7

I have an app that runs great on various devices but when I try to run it on the simulator I get the following error.

pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership

I see where I should remove the * from the id* to solve the problem, however the id* resides inside the coreData.h  so I can't change it.

How can I get rid of this error?

in the NSFetchRequest.h there is a line
id*_additionalPrivateIvars; (this is where the error is coming from)

it is a header inside the framework coreDate/coreData.h

this framework is imported into one of my view controllers

others within coreData are
id** _kvcpropertyAccessors; in NSEntityDescription.h
and 
id*_optimizationHints; in NSManagedObjectModel.h
and
id*_cachedObsInfoByEntity; and id*_contextLabel; in NSManagedObject.h
and
id *_additonalPrivateIvars; inside NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.h
and
id* _oidFactories; in NSPersistentStore.h

don't know if this helps but...

all of these have to do with uploading a video to youtube

I don't have all the devices so I have to run the app on the simulator mostly to look at the different view to make sure everything looks right.  I can't use autoresize because I have various animation when the views run and they have to position things differently depending on the device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

OK here is the code in context within coreData/NSEntityDescription.h

```
#import <Foundation/NSArray.h>
#import <Foundation/NSDictionary.h>
#import <Foundation/NSRange.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@class NSManagedObjectModel;
@class NSManagedObjectContext;
@class NSManagedObject;
@class NSData;
@class NSPropertyDescription;
@class NSRelationshipDescription;
@class NSAttributeDescription;

// Entities describe the "types" of objects available.
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE(10_4,3_0)
@interface NSEntityDescription : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying, NSFastEnumeration> {
@private
    int32_t  _cd_rc;
    id _snapshotClass;
    NSString *_versionHashModifier;
    NSData *_versionHash;
    __weak NSManagedObjectModel *_model;
    NSString *_classNameForEntity;
    Class _instanceClass;
    NSString *_name;
    __weak NSEntityDescription *_rootentity;
    __weak NSEntityDescription *_superentity;
    NSMutableDictionary *_subentities;
    NSMutableDictionary *_properties;
    id _propertyMapping;
    __strong NSRange *_propertyRanges;
    struct __entityDescriptionFlags {
        unsigned int _isAbstract:1;
        unsigned int _shouldValidateOnSave:1;
        unsigned int _isImmutable:1;
        unsigned int _isFlattened:1;
        unsigned int _skipValidation:1;
        unsigned int _hasPropertiesIndexedBySpotlight:1;
        unsigned int _hasPropertiesStoredInTruthFile:1;
        unsigned int _rangesAreInDataBlob:1; 
        unsigned int _hasAttributesWithExternalDataReferences:1;
        unsigned int _hasNonstandardPrimitiveProperties:2;
        unsigned int _hasUniqueProperties:1;
        unsigned int _validationUniqueProperties:1;
        unsigned int _reservedEntityDescription:19;
    } _entityDescriptionFlags;
    __strong void *_extraIvars;
    NSMutableDictionary *_userInfo;
    id _flattenedSubentities;
    id** _kvcPropertyAccessors;  (THIS IS THE OFFENDING CODE LINE)
    long _modelsReferenceIDForEntity;
}
```

and here is the youTubeConnectViewController.h page that imports the coreData.h framework.  //  youTubeConnectViewController.h

```
//  my little world app
//
//  Created by Creatucate on 11/25/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Creatucate. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GData.h"
#import "GDataYouTubeAccessControl.h"
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import "SSKeychain.h"
#define devKey @"AIzaSyDrmQGFblRrH0aBTbR7gsMKxl5QMqgTxcc"


@interface youTubeConnectViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UILabel *UserName;
    IBOutlet UILabel *commas;
    IBOutlet UIButton *signInButton1;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *mEntryCountField;*/
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *catagoryPicker;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *mUploadProgressIndicator;
    IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;
    NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes;
    IBOutlet UITextField *number;
    IBOutlet UILabel *toptitle;
    IBOutlet UILabel *movieTitle;
    IBOutlet UILabel *descp;
    IBOutlet UILabel *tags;
    IBOutlet UILabel *catag;
    IBOutlet UILabel *account;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pub;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pubdef;
    IBOutlet UILabel *pub1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *unlist;
    IBOutlet UILabel *unlistdef;
    IBOutlet UILabel *unlist1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *priv;
    IBOutlet UILabel *privdef;
    IBOutlet UILabel *priv1;
    NSDictionary *pictureDictionary3;
    NSDictionary *pictureDictionary4;
    NSMutableArray *pickerArray;
    IBOutlet UITextField *catagoryField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *catagoryField1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *ViewingField;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonbg;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *pickerback;
    IBOutlet UILabel *okl;
    IBOutlet UIView *SignInButton;
    float downloadingstatus;
    IBOutlet UITextView* terms;
    NSString *authToken;
    BOOL mIsPrivate;
    BOOL mIsPublic;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *signIn;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *fail;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *signOutView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *signIncancel;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ok;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Password;
    IBOutlet UITextField *UserNameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *PasswordField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *movieNameField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *tagsField;
    IBOutlet UITextView *descpView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *accountView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *UserOutField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *PublicField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *PrivateField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *UnlistedField;
    IBOutlet UIButton *chooseButton;
    NSMutableDictionary *SignInDictionary;
    IBOutlet UITextField *PasswordDisplayField;
    IBOutlet UIButton *termsButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *SignOutButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *cancelOutButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *toOutButton;
    IBOutlet UITextField *length;
    IBOutlet UILabel *authfailed;
    IBOutlet UILabel *YouTubesignin;
    IBOutlet UILabel *YouTubesignout;
    IBOutlet UILabel *YouTubesignoutacc;
    IBOutlet UITextView *errorfailed;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
    GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *mEntriesFeed; // user feed of album entries
    GDataServiceTicket *mEntriesFetchTicket;
    NSError *mEntriesFetchError;
    NSString *mEntryImageURLString;
    GDataServiceTicket *mUploadTicket;
    NSURL *mUploadLocationURL;
UIImage *buttonimage3;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *allow;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *done;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap2;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap3;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap4;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap5;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap6;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tap7;
@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *signInButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *buttonimage3;
- (GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *)youTubeService;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *commas;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *length;
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *catagoryField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *catagoryField1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *PasswordDisplayField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIProgressView *mUploadProgressIndicator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *signIn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *signOutView;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *signIncancel;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *signInButton1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *UserName;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *Password;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *UserNameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *PasswordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *movieNameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *tagsField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *chooseButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *catagoryPicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *SignInDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *accountView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *UserOutField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *ViewingField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *PublicField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *PrivateField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *UnlistedField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonbg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *pickerback;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *okl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *fail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *ok;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* terms;
-(IBAction)failure:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancelSignIn:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)hideUserName:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)hidePassword:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)hideTitle:(id)sender;
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)displayPicker:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)dismissPicker:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showTerms:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)signOut:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)CancelOut:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ToOut:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Public:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Private:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Unlisted:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *SignOutButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *cancelOutButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *toOutButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *termsButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *toptitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *movieTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *descp;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *tags;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *catag;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *account;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *pub;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *pub1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *unlist;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *unlist1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *priv;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *priv1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *pubdef;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *unlistdef;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *privdef;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSDictionary *pictureDictionary3;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSDictionary *pictureDictionary4;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIButton *cancel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *number;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes;
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIModalTransitionStyle modalTransitionStyle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *authfailed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *YouTubesignin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *YouTubesignout;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *YouTubesignoutacc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *errorfailed;
-(IBAction)publish:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)SignInSave:(id)sender;
```

This is one example.  I'm sorry there is so much code but I thought I should include everything for you to look at

Comment: You should show your source code and the offending lines from the system header. Simply lopping off an `*` is rarely correct - it *means something*. The error you are seeing is related to ARC and knowing correct ownership is vital for ARC to work. You can edit your question to add extra information. HTH

Comment: Given that every iOS developer has the same header, but no one else is reporting the problem, there's something about your project that causes the error.  You need to provide more context.

Comment: So I changed the framework search path from standard to FacebookSDK and I am now able to have the coreData/coreData.h imported without any errors however now I have errors about linker command and Symbol not found for architecture i386 mostly pertaining to GoogleSignIn and Facebook.  I will post separate question for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is because of the compiler being too new for used SDK. The new clang will enable ARC, but old SDK is not made to compile with ARC.